Crash in React Native App: Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 0
StackTrace:
          Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 0
       at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
       at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
       at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
       at java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:434)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.getAndVerifyPreorderedView(ViewGroup.java:3993)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7689)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:7691)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.gatherTransparentRegion(DecorView.java:611)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:4539)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:3288)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:11344)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1689)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1698)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1153)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:1079)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1646)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
        

I am experiencing this crash on production in my react native app.
Not able to reproduce this till now.
Here are my findings
The crash could occur if the React Native view hierarchy is not fully rendered or if there is a race condition that causes the accessibility service to query for views before they are ready.
The crash suggests that a ViewGroup is trying to access a child view's information at an index that does not exist. This might happen if a view's children are being accessed without verifying that the index is within bounds.
The view hierarchy might be modified (e.g., adding/removing views) while the ViewGroup is iterating over its children, leading to an inconsistency in the list of child views.
The view list might be cleared or not properly populated at the time this method is called, leading to an attempt to access a view that doesn't exist.
These are very generic findings. I am not able to repro this yet

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

hey man, facing similar issue, did you solve it?

I've found a scenario that can cause this crash and managed to reproduce it. In my scenario, there is a video that can be scrolled up and down and a live-streaming room. When you take a screenshot and trigger the scrolling screenshot feature, and at the same time you are scrolling the live-streaming room up or down, it might lead to this crash. Perhaps when the system takes a screenshot, it will call the "gatherTransparentRegion" method to stitch together screenshot information and trigger this issue. Essentially, though, I think the system protection hasn't been done well. Of course, I can't rule out that some ViewGroups in between, like the RecyclerView, might have certain bugs. Maybe the operation on the number of views during a call in the main thread has caused this problem. It's possible that upgrading to AndroidX could solve it. My solution is to override the "gatherTransparentRegion" method of the RecyclerView in between and add a try-catch block for protection.
